# Intercepting and hiding a window before it appears

Tags: c#, c++, windows, message-queue, subclass

I am developing a (in-process) plug-in to application and as part of my plug-in I want to replace the application's tool-tips with my own. However, there is no API available for me to do so, so I've decided to go low-level.

I know the window class of the tool tip, but the question is, how do I detect it being created and how do I close it afterward?

Here's what I thought to do so far:

1. Create a system-wide hook on WM_CREATE
2. When caught, check the class and the process of the WM_CREATE target
3. Verify it is indeed the window I care about:

   - If the process is the one my plug-in is sitting in
   - And if the class is of the correct type
   - And if the correct application is in focus (in case of multiple applications)
4. Send a WM_DESTROY to the created window and create my own window at its position instead

How does it sound? Assuming there is indeed no API to handle the tooltips, is there a simpler way for what I need?

Thanks!

P.S Tagged as C++/C# as I intend to write it in these 2 languages (C++ for system-wide hook, C# for everything else)

Comment: Tooltips are often done by creating and keeping  just *one* tooltip window per top-level parent window. That tooltip window is then adjusted and shown when needed and hidden when not. So you would need to track when the window is shown, not when it's created, and you obviously would not want to destroy it (you might get away with hiding it).

Comment: @Leo: Thanks for the comment. That's possibly very true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know the type of the window you want to block, you can simply subclass it and handle the destruction in your own `WndProc`. Use [GetClassLongPtr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633581%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with `GCL_WNDPROC` on the tooltip class, use [SetClassLongPtr()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633589%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) with `GCL_WNDPROC` to set your own `WndProc` and have it call DestroyWindow() on `WM_CREATE` and call the old `WndProc` for the rest..

Comment: I am confused... GetClassLongPtr() required a HWND, but in case of the tooltip, it wasn't created yet. Are you saying I can use GetClassLongPtr()/SetClassLongPtr() to subclass a not-yet-existing window?

Comment: Yeah, you need to create a dummy tooltip window first and use that.

Comment: @kichik: Interesting... And if I do that, all the future instances of a window of that class will use that MessagePump?

Comment: Indeed. Though it's not a question of MessagePump, but rather a WndProc. You can also re-register the class with GetClassInfoEx(), UnregisterClass() and RegisterClassEx().

Comment: @kichik: That seems to be working great and it is a lot easier than hooking. Thanks!

Comment: @kichik: I'm afraid the solution worked great during prototyping but I am having issues when trying to make it work in the real process, perhaps you have an idea? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4371470/createwindowex-fails-with-error-cannot-find-wnd-class Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This won't work.  Consider the view of the application that you're replacing the tooltips of and assuming that you could tell it to destroy windows.  What will happen when the app decides that it needs to close the tooltip?  It doesn't have the handle of your new window, it has the handle of the old window, which you've destroyed.  Time for things to go wrong.

Your plugin system needs to explicitly support replacing the tooltips if you want this to work smoothly.  Perhaps an optional part of the plugin framework could be a RequestTooltip function.  If it doesn't exist, or returns null, or whatever then the default tooltips are used, otherwise your plugin provided ones are used.

Comment: Regarding the first part. That's true, it is more complex than that - I'll need to start tracking the mouse by myself to hide my own window. The original application won't be able to hide the tool-tip for me, however, I don't see why it should cause a problem. For example, if there is an issue with destroying the "old" tooltip, I can try hiding it instead, then the destroy would work fine (in fact, I can even hook the destroying of the old tooltip to hide my new one).

Comment: Regarding the second issue: I am afraid the application has no API which it queries about the existence of tooltips so I simply can't do that =\