# CreateWindowEx fails with ERROR_CANNOT_FIND_WND_CLASS

Tags: windows, winapi, createwindow

I am trying to create a window with a certain class type ("VSDebugger CDataTipWnd"), however, when I run CreateWindowEx it fails, and GetLastError tells me that the class wasn't found. Here is the code for reference, though it shouldn't matter:

```
const Win32WindowStyles dwStyle = Win32WindowStyles.WS_POPUP;
IntPtr wnd = NativeMethods.CreateWindowEx(0L, "VSDebugger CDataTipWnd", "MyWindow",
                                                  dwStyle, 100, 100, 100, 100, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

I am running as a plug-in in the process and I know that a Window of this class is created before (I made sure of that using Winspector/Spy++), yet, when I try to create a window of this type myself, it doesn't work and I can't figure out why.

The [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632679%28VS.85%29.aspx) says that the "The class name can be any name registered with RegisterClass or RegisterClassEx, provided that the module that registers the class is also the module that creates the window. The class name can also be any of the predefined system class names. For a list of system class names, see the Remarks section." is it possible that the RegisterClass was indeed created in another module (dll/exe)? Does merely creating a class in another module make it inaccessible by name from another module?? If so, can I still find that class somehow and create a window with it?

Thanks!
Vitaly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing IntPtr.Zero to the HINSTANCE argument.

The HINSTANCE of the module (EXE or DLL) which registered the class must be provided to CreateWindowEx.

If you think the main EXE registered the class then you can get its HINSTANCE via GetModuleHandle(IntPtr.Zero).

If another DLL registered the class then you'll need some way to know which one and get its HINSTANCE/HMODULE (the two are the same these days).

Comment: Using GetModuleHandle(null) doesn't seem to be working... I guess I'll try enumerating all the modules and find the correct one :| Isn't there a better way? Like asking the process which module created class X?

Comment: If you can see an instance of the window class on screen, use the Spy++ tool that comes with Visual Studio to locate that window (you can drag the crosshair over it to find it by simply pointing at it), then look on the Class tab where it'll tell you the Instance Handle. If you then switch to Process Explorer, select the process and turn on the DLL view (lower panel), it should be the DLL whose Base column shows the same number. (Note that Process Explorer does not pad the numbers, so e.g. 0x600000 is easily confused with 0x6000000 etc.) In your code, try LoadLibrary on that DLL for the handle

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! It was a great tip and it did work... I can now access the class (still can't create a window out of it :( ). But anyway, I learned a lot! Thanks!

Comment: As written in the MSDN documentation, passing a null pointer for the hInstance parameter of CreateWindowEx is allowed (the parameter is specified as optional, so a null pointer is okay).

Answer (score 1):

That's probably the case. Does the program provide an API to do this? You mention you're running as a plugin to it - I'd think that'd be the way to do it.

Comment: I'm afraid not... I only went this way after giving up on doing it differently.